# Sysinternals' Portmon: Error 2

Tags: serial-port

When I try to connect to local ports, *Computer -> Connect local*, using [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) v. 3.02, I'm getting an error message, *Error 2*, in a small error dialog box:

[image]

I run the tool as an administrator (if not, I get error 6).

By the way this is a Windows 7 x64. On 32-bit, in Windows 7 x86, it works fine. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Same error with v3.02 but the PortMon v3.03 works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/portmon#portmon-3x

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Sysinternals' Portmon works only on 32-bit versions of Windows. It does not support 64-bit (probably its driver is not signed).

From the Portmon homepage:

- Runs on:

  - Client: Windows XP (32-bit) and higher (32-bit).
  - Server: Windows Server 2003 (32-bit) and higher (32-bit).

Comment: @JAG, It's 2011 and they still haven't updated it. Pretty sure it's never happening.

Comment: It's 2012 and still a no-go on x64.

Comment: It's 2013 and still not happening.

Comment: Its 2014 and still not happening :)

Comment: It's 2015 and no updates.  Struggling with it and compatibility mode isn't working with a USB device on a Surface.

Comment: Now it's 2016 :)

Comment: It's 2027 here in the future; and still not updates.

Comment: +1 for the latest comment..

BDW, hope someone will do this. we need such tool nowadays and its 64bit world :(

Comment: MS rather monitors their users in 2017

Comment: It's 5000 B.C. over here, and we just deleted the last version. Guess it overflowed...

Comment: 2018, still no update and compatibility mode not working on Win7 x64.

Comment: Well ... it's 2019. Face it.

Comment: 2021 now...  My project has been on hold for a decade.

Comment: It's 2022 and still not working :/

Comment: No comment for 2020, suspicious...

Comment: Well, FractalSpace already told us that there is still no update in 2027.

Comment: Well, it's 2024 and it's still not working because the driver isn't signed :-/

Answer (score 11):

In Windows Explorer, right click on `portmon.exe` --> select *Properties* --> click the *Compatibility* tab, and Run in Windows XP compatibility mode. It works fine like that in Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I can open but it can't capture my USB to serial port. Any idea?

Comment: This will allow you to "connect local" but not actually open the port. My guess is that this has to do with a unsigned driver (required in Windows 7/8) or a non-x64 driver.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work on Win 10 x64

Answer (score 6):

"Error 2" is "Cannot find the file specified", that is, cannot find a required DLL file.

Originally, you got this error when you tried to run Portmon from a network location: that broke the security trust, causing Portmon to be untrusted (or perhaps just messing up the search path somehow).

On my copy of Windows 7 64 bit, Microsoft [Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) (depends.exe) tells me that PORTMSYS.SYS (the file created/loaded by Portmon.exe), has unresolved dependencies on ci.dll, clfs.sys, hal.dll and kdcom.dll.

Those are the

```
code integrity
common log file system
hardware abstraction layer
kernel debugger com
```

libraries, and they aren't actually missing: if they were, Windows wouldn't boot. However, I don't see a copy of those files in SysWow64. This suggests to me that the problem is not with portman.sys: the problem is with the win32 compatibility layer in Windows 7/64 bit: It doesn't support debug properly.

It is now 2018. There is no 64-bit version of Portmon. Serial ports are a legacy standard. The Windows 7 problem was fixed by the release of Windows 8.1. However, there is a faint chance that some Visual Studio utility or security update back-ported to Windows 7 will fix the problem. Perhaps someone who is familiar with SysWow and debugging will comment.

Answer (score 5):

I've used AccessPort 
http://sudt.com/en/ap/download.htm and it works great. Very similar to Portmon

Comment: -1 Not at all similar. It can't sniff, it can only connect if the connection isn't already opened, so basically like putty and the dozen other boring tools.

Comment: @DerManu I just tried the tool on Win10 with a FTDI FT232R and it works just fine. I see all the communication flowing between my application through the serial port to my device. So definitely a +1 !

Comment: @DerManu It can, but it's not intuitive. You have to select the port with Monitor -> Ports, then start the monitoring with Monitor -> Start Monitor. Make sure Capture Events is ticked in the Monitor menu.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of portmon for Windows x64, you can use an emulator of a pair of virtual COM ports and a simple program that will connect the physical port and one of the virtual ones, as well as perform the logging function.

To create a pair of virtual COM ports you can use:

- [com0com](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/) (preferably version "com0com-2.2.2.0-x64-fre-signed", because it contains signed x64 driver)
- [Virtual Serial Ports Emulator](http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) (VSPE), every time it starts on x64 it asks to purchase a driver, but it works even if you refuse.

Simple mapping and logging program can be found e.g. [here](http://selenur.ru/?p=466) or you can write it yourself, it is simple.

The sequence of actions is follows:

- Сreate a pair of virtual COM ports using emulator (for example, COM28 and COM29)
- Let the external device be connected to the computer COM1 port. In the program, whose exchange with external device we want to listen to, we set up a port COM28 (instead of СОМ1) for communication.
- In the mapping program, we set up that we want to bind and log ports COM1 and COM29 (don't forget to set the port baud rate).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461794/whats-a-good-free-serial-port-monitor-for-reverse-engineering) mentions [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). It creates two virtual serial ports and emulates a null modem cable between them. It claims to be able to run on 64 bit Windows. I'm not sure whether it comes with software that lets you just pipe input from a real port into one of the virtual ports. One of the FAQ's says that you can turn on logging.

I guess in the worst case, you could write your own small program that pipes data from a real port to one of the virtual ports and logs it all.

There's also [this question on open-source alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5089516/4794) that mentions a couple of projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Portmon in compatibility mode, it will work.

Check *[Make older programs run in this version of Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-programs-run#1TC=windows-7)*.

It says:

> To run the Program Compatibility troubleshooter:
>
> 1. Open the Program Compatibility troubleshooter by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type troubleshooter, and then click Troubleshooting. Under Programs, click Run programs made for previous versions of Windows.
> 2. Follow the instructions in the troubleshooter.

The above is a public explanation from Microsoft for a common situation when running older applications in Windows.

But, I can say it briefly;

1. Right click on portmon.exe
2. Select menu about "troubleshooting compatibility problem" or something like that (I'm using a foreign version of Windows, so I don't see correct name of that menu in English.)
3. Select automatic mode
4. It will detect the problem and recommend Windows XP (SP2) mode
5. Select it and execute Portmon again.

I hope it works!

Comment: Please post the content of the link in your answer, so that if the link becomes unavailable in the future, your answer would remain relevant.

Comment: It did not work on Windows 10 64-bit when I tried it. It offered Windows 7 compatibility mode and the result was the "Error 2" message box.

Comment: Not working for me either. even if I manually set compatibility to Windows XP SP2.

Comment: The program starts without error 2, but the capture button is disabled. I think the driver is only 32 bit.

Comment: Disabled capture button is a timing bug in the last version of Portmon., which prevents the selection of the local target computer.  Because it's a timing bug, it's not always on everything. It is avoided by using the previous Portmon version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Portmon you can also use the [IO Ninja](https://ioninja.com/) program with the ["Serial Monitor"](https://ioninja.com/plugins/serial-monitor.html) plugin.

It gives a little less information than Portmon, but in a more understandable form. The main thing is, just like a Portmon, it allows you to see the data that is transmitted between a third-party application and an external device via a serial port. The program works under modern versions of Windows (I tried it myself on Windows 10 x64). The aforementioned plugin "Serial Monitor" is paid (but has an evaluation period).

**Note:** the port that you want to monitor must first be connected to the "IO Ninja" program, and then opened in a third-party application whose exchange with an external device you want to track.

Answer (score -1):

Don't start Portmon from a network drive/path or something else.

Copy on to the hard disk drive, e.g. on the desktop, restart and try again!

Comment: this doesn't make any difference, at least in my case- win7 64bit, running as admin. Running as a regular use gets me error 6.

Comment: Location of the files makes no difference at all in this case.

Comment: This helps, the application starts, but it won't connect. Win 2012R2.

Answer (score -3):

Just to test that the hardware is working, you could perhaps boot a [Linux live CD](http://www.livecdlist.com/) and run the `statserial` and/or `minicom` program to verify that it works. The [Knoppix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoppix) distribution seems to contain both those programs.

Serial ports on Linux are named `/dev/ttyS0` for COM1, `/dev/ttyS1` for COM2, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The hardware is working just fine, it's just portmon app. I've tested in W7 x86 and it works without problems.

It seems to be an incompatibility with Windows 7 x64.

Comment: It is also incompatible with Windows Vista x64... in case there was any doubt.