# Spy on serial port communication

Tags: serial-port

I have the following setup. I have a hardware device connected to COM1 and COM2. In order to test it I have software simulators connected to COM1 and COM2 (RS-232 ports). These simulators receive and transmit data via my hardware device.

I need to calculate the throughput time of my hardware device. For example, if the simulator on COM1 sends a message at time A then I need to establish when it arrives at COM2, giving me Time B. The throughput is then simply B-A.

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a free serial port spy which works accurately enough for my circumstances. I've tried  Sysinternals' [Portmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/portmon), but it is only accurate to a second and I need to know the answer to the nearest tenth of a second. I also tried Free Serial Port Monitor, but it has inaccurate timestamping.

Any suggestions on suitable software?

Comment: Have you considered [Serial Monitor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/serial-monitor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Portmon. Change the time format; it can show the time in milliseconds (click the timer button on the tool bar - or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or menu *Options* → *Clock Time*).

Or use Portmon with more data you can get accurately.

Comment: "Sysinternals' Portmon works only on 32-bit versions of Windows." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356470/sysinternals-portmon-error-2