# Seeking serial port read example

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I want to read from COM1 at 115200,n,8,1 (preferably a blocking call, but I can add that. And I don't need threading).

The only code that I can find is on Stack Overflow in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036716/serial-comm-using-writefile-readfile) (Microsoft also had [some useful info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx)).

The author says that his code works, and I don't doubt him, but when I run the code I don't receive any characters, even though the port opened correctly (if I check with a terminal program, data are being sent).

Can someone please post a URL to some example C code? Thanks.

FWIW, here's my code:

```
// +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
E_boolean OpenCom1(void)
{
   COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

   comPorthandle = CreateFile("COM1",  // Specify port device: default "COM1"
   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       // Specify mode that open device.
   0,                                  // the device isn't shared.
   NULL,                               // the object gets a default security.
   OPEN_EXISTING,                      // Specify which action to take on file.
   0,                                  // default (not overlapped i/o).
   NULL);                              // default (hTemplate must be NULL for COM devices).

   if (comPorthandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      return False;

   deviceControlBlock.DCBlength = sizeof(deviceControlBlock);

    if((GetCommState(comPorthandle, &deviceControlBlock) == 0))
    {
      // CodeMe: do what?
      return False;
    }

    deviceControlBlock.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    deviceControlBlock.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    deviceControlBlock.Parity   = NOPARITY;
    deviceControlBlock.ByteSize = DATABITS_8;
    deviceControlBlock.fRtsControl = 0;

    if (!SetCommState(comPorthandle, &deviceControlBlock))
    {
      // CodeMe: do what?
      return False;
    }

#if 0
// alternative to GetCommState() and SetCommState()
// both versions succeed
   if (!BuildCommDCB("115200,n,8,1", &deviceControlBlock))
    {
      // CodeMe: do what?
      return False;
    }
#endif 

    // set short timeouts on the comm port.
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    if (!SetCommTimeouts(comPorthandle, &timeouts))
    {
      // CodeMe: do what?
      return False;
    }

   return True;
}//OpenCom1()

// +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
void      ReadCharacterFromCom1(INPUT char *theCharacter)
{
   DWORD numBytesRead;

   numBytesRead = 0;

   while (numBytesRead == 0)
   {
      ReadFile(comPorthandle,           // handle of file to read
               theCharacter,            // store read data here
               sizeof(theCharacter),    // number of bytes to read
               &numBytesRead,           // pointer to number of bytes actually read
               NULL);
   }
   return;
}//ReadCharacterFromCom1()
```

Comment: Simply set up the port whichever way you want, then use regular `read` calls on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one problem in this code:

```
    sizeof(theCharacter),
```

replace this with

```
    sizeof(char),
```

because you want to read one byte, and sizeof(char*) is 4 or 8. Possibly there is something else, but you need to show more code.

Also, use Portmon program http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx to see whether data is received - you can run it together with your program.

Comment: +1 An excellent point (and a mistake which I have made before). I will check it out as soon as I can aandd get back to you.

Comment: Ok, now it is reading chars, but they seem like non-ascii values & I am only sending text. More tomorrow am.

Comment: Validate this with PortMon.

Comment: +1 but, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356470/sysinternals-portmon-error-2 says "Sysinternals Portman works only on x86 versions of Windows. It does not support x64 (probably its driver is not signed).     However, when I use another terminal program, I recieve the data correctly. You answered my question with sizeof(), so I will award and ask a new queestion about receiving garbage. Thanks
From portmon homepage:
Runs on: Client: Windows XP (32-bit) and higher (32-bit). Server: Windows Server 2003 (32-bit) and higher (32-bit)."